# Remove frame buster in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to load a page with frame buster inside. Its seems that in everypage that have this javascript, every link inside doesn't work, it always returns to index. but some page doesn't have the framebuster and act normally.

```
if (parent.frames.length > 0) {
top.location.replace(document.location);
}
```

Is android webview considered as an Iframe? I can load the web normally in chrome, maybe im missing a config?

Here is the code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;


public class AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://xxxx");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have javascript enabled in your webview? It's kind of hard to find the problem without any code

```
yourwebviewname.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The WebView is not considered an iframe.